# Returning focus to input after clicking button not working

Tags: javascript

This has got to be really simple, but I just didn't find any answer.  I have a simple menu to enter special characters into a search text box.  Its doing its job but if i click a character the menu will (blur) and the focus is not returned to the field.  As long as the cursor is in the field and/or I click on the characters menu, I want the menu to remain visible.   On the event listner for the menu buttons, the first and last lines work.  The text is appended to the search box, and hello world logged to the console.  But the menu does not show, and the text box does not regain the focus.  What is wrong here?

[problem demo here](https://coastsystems.net/julakan/fr/home/)

```js
let searchInput = document.querySelector('#search-input');
let charsMenu = document.querySelector('.charsmenu');

// add event listeners to textbox                                                                                                                                             
searchInput.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  toggleDisplay(charsMenu, true);
});

searchInput.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  toggleDisplay(charsMenu, false);
});

function toggleDisplay(element, show) {
  if (show)
    element.style.display = 'block';
  else
    element.style.display = 'none';
}

let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.charsmenu li');

listItems.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
    searchInput.value += `${event.currentTarget.innerHTML}`;
    toggleDisplay(charsMenu, true);
    searchInput.focus();
    console.log("Hello world!");
  });
});
```

Comment: I can't see any problem on your code. Did you try 'click' instead of 'mousedown'. Maybe mousedown has a different application, or maybe unreleased mouse button may block focus change.

Comment: You probably need to set an arbitrary timeout after mousedown before trying to focus on the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are, after mousedown is fired, the `<li>` element is going to steal focus away from the input element. Therefore you will want to defer setting focus on the input element at the end of the call stack, i.e.:

```
window.setTimeout(() => searchInput.focus(), 0);
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
let searchInput = document.querySelector('#search-input');
let charsMenu = document.querySelector('.charsmenu');

// add event listeners to textbox                                                                                                                                             
searchInput.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  toggleDisplay(charsMenu, true);
});

searchInput.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  toggleDisplay(charsMenu, false);
});

function toggleDisplay(element, show) {
  if (show)
    element.style.display = 'block';
  else
    element.style.display = 'none';
}

let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.charsmenu li');

listItems.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
    searchInput.value += `${event.currentTarget.innerHTML}`;
    toggleDisplay(charsMenu, true);
    window.setTimeout(() => searchInput.focus(), 0);
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.charsmenu {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.charsmenu li {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="charsmenu">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
  </ul>

  <input type="text" id="search-input" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yes!   That did the deed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Terry said, the focus is being stolen anyway.
My solution is just add `preventDefault()` before the focus setting:

```js
listItems.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
    searchInput.value += `${event.currentTarget.innerHTML}`;
    toggleDisplay(charsMenu, true);
    event.preventDefault();
    searchInput.focus();
  });
});
```

By the way, you can have event listener on a `<UL>` instead of each `<LI>`.

Comment: This works equally well as the accepted answer.  Thanks also for the UL suggestion.